# Can you preinstall mvc on a Sharepoint Server

Tags: sharepoint

So at work we are currently using SharePoint 2010 for all our sites. But something came up that we need to have a site up that is not SharePoint but an ASP.NET application. Is it possible to host an asp.net site on the same server that is hosting all our SharePoint Sites?

Thanks in advance. and please help in a tight deadline thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, generally this is possible. If you ASP.NET app runs within a separate IIS web site, then there should be no issues. What you need to pay attention to are possible conflicts between DLLs in GAC and you ASP.NET app's dependencies. For example, if one of your SharePoint sites uses a library `X.dll` as part of a customization *and* it is (unfortunatelly) deployed into GAC *and* the ASP.NET app relies on a slightly different version of the same `X.dll`, that may cause a conflict.

You can even incorporate plain ASP.NET applications into SharePoint web sites; however, in such case you may run into some issues depending on the app's internals (again DLL conflicts, authentication conflicts etc.).

Comment: Sorry if this question is stupid, but how can my ASP.NET application run within a separate IIS in the same server of sharepoint?

Comment: Just create a new IIS web site using IIS Manager and deploy the app into it. Deployment depends on your app's specifics.

Comment: oh okay makes sense, I just heard around that once you made a SharePoint server, you couldn't host asp.net sites on the same server. But thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Of course, it is *better* to *dedicate* machines for SharePoint. It's a complicated beast.

Comment: that's true, but my job is only requiring me to have one asp.net application to be out of SharePoint. Wouldn't want to have one server only hosting one site?